# Enforce template function to be T=B* inside a class<std::unique_ptr<B>>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unique-ptr, template-specialization

I have a storage class, it can add/remove element.

Most of its public functions share a very similar signature as shown function :-

```
template<class T> class Storage{
    public: void add(T& t){ ... }
    //... other fields,functions
}
```

A great thing is that `T` can be value or raw pointer.

Now I want to upgrade this storage to support `T=std::unique_ptr` too.
This is what I want to accomplish:-

```
Storage<std::unique_ptr<B>> store;
B* b = new B();
store.add(b);   //my attempt - it is currently not supported
```

Here is my draft to support the new feature:-

```
template<class T> class Storage{
    public: template<class TWeak> void add(TWeak& tw){  ...   }
    //... other fields,functions
}
```

From the draft, I think it is somewhat dangerous to use `TWeak` as a template argument - `TWeak` can be anything.

It is contradict to my intention that `TWeak` can only be `T's weakpointer` , roughly speaking.

More specifically, I want to enforce this rule :-

```
When   T=std::unique_ptr<B>   ==>    TWeak have to be B* or std::unique_ptr<B>
When   T=B*                   ==>    TWeak have to be B*
When   T=B                    ==>    TWeak have to be B
```

How to enforce the rules elegantly?
A solution that has 2 `add` functions is still acceptable.

Comment: What should add do with the unique_ptr? Assume ownership? If so, why not make an add(T&&) function instead?

Comment: @rubenvb  Yes, assume ownership.   It is ok to create a function `add(T&&)`, but I think it doesn't solve the problem about the rule enforcement.

Comment: First, ask yourself: why are these rules in place? Then, see if it works without. Then, check `std::vector`'s implementation to see how it handles these things. If this doesn't clear things up, add some `static_assert`s using `std::is_same` to enforce the rule with a clear error message. Chances are though, these conversions will already be enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @rubenvb  (1) While I check `std::vector`, I found limitation   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125631/best-way-to-delete-a-stdunique-ptr-from-a-vector-with-a-raw-pointer   Thus, I assume that `std::vector` is not a good example.   .... (2) About `static_assert`, I don't have enough talent.  "Ami Tavory" tried to do it (belowed answer), but not finish because it is cumbersome. ... (3) About "already be enforced", I will be more pleased if I can also control it myself. I don't like unreadable compiler error about template.

Comment: Deleting a unique_ptr through a raw pointer implies there might be other raw pointers left pointing to the deleted object, contradicting any assurances you may have about the ownership of that object. This is a recipe for disaster. I strongly suggest you rethink what you are doing.

Comment: @rubenvb  Is it more appropriate if I call remove(std::unique_ptr(...)) ?   I aim to use a raw pointer as a weak pointer (no ownership, I have a way to know when it will be deleted), is it also a bad decision?

Comment: using a raw pointer as a non-owning pointer is not bad, but using that non-owning pointer to delete the object (albeit indirectly) is, IMHO. Deleting an object is an owner's sole responsibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124280/discussion-between-javalover-and-rubenvb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the interface simple, you can extend the `Storage` with a specialization, which serves enclosing types like `unique_ptr`:

```
template<class T>
class Storage<std::unique_ptr<T>> : public Storage<T*>{
  public: using Storage<T*>::add;
  public: void add(std::unique_ptr<T>& t){ ... }  // 
};
```

We inherit, `Storage<T*>` because:

1. `T*` goes well with `unique_ptr<T>` as per a requirement in your
   question
2. It includes all the common methods. The special methods like `add()`
   are defined separately and `using` directive is used to unhide the
   base methods

Usage:

```
Storage<int> si; si.add(/*int variable*/);
Storage<int*> spi; spi.add(/*int* variable*/);
Storage<std::unique_ptr<int>> su; su.add(/*int* or unique_ptr<int> variable*/);
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/hNmbUH).

Comment: Wow! I didn't know I can derive it like that.  How would compiler know which one to pick - `Storage<T>` vs `Storage<std::unique_ptr<T>>`?  What is the technique (same class but with different `<>`) called? ... template specialization? (i.e. where can I find more information?)

Comment: @javaLover, actually compiler has its own way of finding the best match for template specialization. In this case, it's straight forward though. You are passing `unique_ptr<X>` and hence the same class specialization is selected. In case, if you want to pass `shared_ptr` or some other wrapper instead of `unique_ptr`, then also there is a way. We need to modify the specialized class definition a bit. I will update my answer on same.

Answer (score 1):

> More specifically, I want to enforce this rule :-
>
> When   `T=std::unique_ptr<B>`   ==>    `TWeak` have to be `B*` or std::unique_ptr
>
> When   `T=B*`                   ==>    `TWeak` have to be `B*`
>
> When   `T=B`                    ==>    `TWeak` have to be `B`

You can write an "enforcer" class with specializations, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename B, typename Tweak>
class tweak_enforcer
{   
    static_assert(std::is_same<Tweak, B>::value, "must be of same type");
};

template<typename B, typename Tweak>
class tweak_enforcer<std::unique_ptr<B>, B, Tweak>
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<Tweak, B*>::value || std::is_same<Tweak, std::unique_ptr<B>>::value, "must be of pointer type");
};
```

Each specialization uses a [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to check one or more expected type matches via [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Then you can use it like this (uncommenting any of the commented lines causes a build failure with an appropriate message):

```
int main() {
    { tweak_enforcer<int, int, int> dummy; }
    // { tweak_enforcer<int *, int *, int> dummy; }
    { tweak_enforcer<int *, int *, int *> dummy; }
    { tweak_enforcer<std::unique_ptr<int>, int, int *> dummy; }
    { tweak_enforcer<std::unique_ptr<int>, int, std::unique_ptr<int>> dummy; }
    // { tweak_enforcer<std::unique_ptr<int>, int, std::shared_ptr<int>> dummy; }
}
```

Comment: I notice that tweak_enforcer want 3 arguments.  Can it be only two - like `tweak_enforcer<std::unique_ptr<int>, int*>`?  For example, in the class's scope, I know that `TWeak=int*` and `T=std::unique_ptr<int>`, but I don't know how to "access" `int`.

Comment: @javaLover If I understand you correctly, I agree; started writing this as a traits class, that takes two arguments, and defines `type` as what it should be. The thing is, the correspondence is not 1:1. You have a case where 1 type matches to 2 acceptable types. The only way I know to do this is by defining `type` to be some sort of typelist, which is extremely cumbersome.